# Graph complex inequality $|1/z|<1$, when $z \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-numbers

### Problem

Graph complex inequality $|1/z|<1$, when $z \in \mathbb{C}$

### Attempt to solve

if i set $z=x+iy$ when $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}, z \in \mathbb{C}$

$$ |\frac{1}{x+iy}|<1 $$

Trying to multiply denominator and nominator with complex conjugate.

$$ |\frac{x-iy}{(x+iy)(x-iy)}| <3 $$

$$ |\frac{x-iy}{x\cdot x + x(-iy) + iy \cdot x + iy (-iy)}| <3$$

$$ |\frac{x-iy}{x^2-xyi+xyi-(iy)^2}|<3 $$

Utilize the fact that $i^2=-1$

$$ |\frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}|<3 $$

$$ |\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{iy}{x^2+y^2}|<3 $$
$$ \sqrt{(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})^2+(-\frac{iy}{x^2+y^2})^2}<3 $$
$$ (\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})^2+(-\frac{iy}{x^2+y^2})^2<3^2 $$

$$ \frac{x^2}{x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4}+\frac{i^2y^2}{x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4}<3^2 $$

$$  $$

I tried to plot the inequality with wolfram alpha and i got area outside of circle in $(0,0)

[image]

Not quite sure if this is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just write
$$ |1/z| < 1 \quad\iff\quad |z| > 1 \quad\iff\quad x^2+y^2 > 1. $$

Comment: @MathLover Thanks for the edit. I usually use $\Leftrightarrow$ rather than $\iff$ for some reason. Is there any real difference other than \iff being quicker to type and the arrow being a bit more stretched out?

Comment: It's just a matter of preference. I think `\iff` looks nicer (to me at least :)).

Comment: @MathLover Alright, I think I should switch to it too. Saves me 10 characters per equivalence. =)

Answer (score 3):

|z| > 1 
that means outside the circle of radius 1 , centered at (0,0)